# inline asm, error with

Tags: c++, c, assembly

I'm getting this error:

> Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call. This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.

I don't know how to solve it,  can anyone help me?

My code is:

```
#include "common.h"

char* file = "c:\\town.las";
char* file_mode = "r";


#pragma pack(1)
struct LASHEADER
{
    char LASF[4];
};


void main()
{
    LASHEADER lasHeader;
    FILE* of;

    __asm
    {
            push ebp       


            mov     eax, file_mode
            push    eax
            push    file
            call    fopen
            mov of, eax

            mov esi, esp
            mov eax, DWORD PTR of
            push eax
            push 1
            push 4 // this should be sizeof LASHEADER

            lea ecx, DWORD PTR lasHeader
            push ecx

            call DWORD PTR fread
            add esp, 16
            cmp esi, esp



            mov eax, of
            push eax
            call fclose


    }
}
```

how can i do what it asked? i tried to do push ebp and pop at the end with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

The error says exactly what's wrong.  You are not consistently restoring the stack pointer after function calls.  This looks like VC output.  You should compile a small program that calls `fopen`, `fread`, and `fclose` to see what's done with the stack.  Every function parameter `push` must be matched by 4 bytes added to `esp` before returning.

Here's a guess at what will work:

```
        push ebp       

        push    file_mode  ; 1 word
        push    file       ; 2 words
        call    fopen
        mov of, eax        ; this could be wrong depending on compiler

        mov esi, esp
        mov eax, DWORD PTR of
        push eax ; 3 words
        push 1 ; 4 words
        push 4 ; 5 words

        lea ecx, DWORD PTR lasHeader
        push ecx ; 6 words

        call DWORD PTR fread

        mov eax, of ; again could be wrong depending on compiler
        push eax  ; 7 words
        call fclose

        add esp, 28 ; REMOVE 7 words from the stack

        pop ebp
```

Comment: You missed a `push eax` :)

Comment: @Jester There was a useless load eax and push, when pushing a constant was possible, so I replaced it.  Is that the one you mean?

Comment: thanks that clears it up a little, i am however getting a new error now "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'lasHeader' was corrupted." but i will try what you suggested.

Comment: No, I mean you have a `push eax` that you forgot to count into the number of words pushed, which should be 7 according to my count.